# Texture not applying in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I'm just learning three.js and so far everything has been going good except for when it comes to textures. Whenever I try to apply a texture it doesn't work. And that's when I'm basically copying and pasting tutorial codes to tweak and all I'm doing is changing the image to one I have. The weirdest part is when the pathname is incorrect, it displays the object (in this case, the floor plane) all black as expected but when it *is* correct, nothing is displayed except the axes for direction. The tutorial is [here](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/). It's lesson 1 (though I've gotten to lesson 6 using plain colors as substitutes for textures), and the source code isn't on the page; you need to right click and view the page source. The part where the code applies the checkerboard texture is near the end in the section called 'floor'. Also, I even tried seeing if it was because it didn't load before it rendered but that's not the case.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add some code?

Comment: The code was taken to tinker with from the link I put above; I guess it was pretty hard to see (on the here) but here's the link again: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/